# Angular 4 DropDown Error When Displaying Default Value

Tags: html, angular

I have the following form:

```
<form class="row" name="powerPlantSearchForm" (ngSubmit)="f.valid && searchPowerPlants()" #f="ngForm" novalidate>
          <div class="form-group col-xs-3" >
            <label for="powerPlantName">PowerPlant Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control-small" [ngClass]="{ 'has-error': f.submitted && !powerPlantName.valid }" name="powerPlantName" [(ngModel)]="model.powerPlantName" #powerPlantName="ngModel" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-xs-3" >
            <label for="powerPlantType">PowerPlant Type</label>
            <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="model.powerPlantType" name="powerPlantType">
              <option value="" disabled>--Select Type--</option>
              <option [ngValue]="powerPlantType" *ngFor="let powerPlantType of powerPlantTypes">
                {{ powerPlantType }}
              </option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-xs-3" >
            <label for="organizationName">Organization Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control-small" name="powerPlantOrganization" [(ngModel)]="model.powerPlantOrg" #organizationName="ngModel" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-xs-3" >
            <label for="powerPlantStatus">PowerPlant Active Status</label>
            <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="model.powerPlantStatus" name="powerPlantStatus">
              <option disabled >--Select Status--</option>
              <option [ngValue]="powerPlantStatus" *ngFor="let powerPlantStatus of powerPlantStatuses">
                {{ powerPlantStatus }}
              </option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-3 col-xs-4">
            <button [disabled]="loading" class="btn btn-primary">Search For PowerPant's...</button>
            <img *ngIf="loading" src="data:image/gif;base64,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" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-3 col-xs-3">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="f.reset()">Reset Search Criteria</button>
          </div>
        </form>
```

When I render the page, I could not see the default value being shown in the drop down fields. Here is the screenshot that I see when the page is loaded:

[image]

I would like to have the page look like this (for the PowerPlantType field) when it is loaded!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your template

```
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="model.powerPlantType" name="powerPlantType">
          <option value="">--Select Type--</option>
          <option [ngValue]="powerPlantType" *ngFor="let powerPlantType of powerPlantTypes">
            {{ powerPlantType }}
          </option>
</select>
```

and make sure in your component assign **powerPlantType null value**

```
 constructor()
   {
      this.model.powerPlantType=''

   }
```

Comment: Well that was it! Thanks a ton for the help!

Comment: I wanted to, but I have to wait for some minutes before I could! I will definitely mark it as the right answer! Please also upvote for my post. I have tried to find an answer and I couldn't until your reply!

Comment: @sparkr this is basic question boss

Comment: I was missing the setting in the constructor and I could not find this with a simple google search!